# How to make .htaccess redirect all links to .html suffix

Tags: .htaccess

```
http://advokat-malov.ru/index.php
http://advokat-malov.ru/ 
http://advokat-malov.ru/index.html
```

how to make htaccess redirect .php, or seo links(without extension) to .html

how to make it using rewriteCond and rewriteRule or redirectmatch

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
# This will change all .php to .html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]


# This will add .html to all urls that are not in the white list
# White list extensions php, html, css, js, less, jpg, png, gif
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(php|html|css|js|less|jpg|png|gif)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Comment: for example if i am on the main page www.example.com - it will redirect to www.example.com/.html, but i want it to not redirect if its the main page, if i am on www.example.com/category/test(without extension) or www.example.com/category/test.php, i want it all redirect to .html extension

Answer (score 0):

in this line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

You changed the order of php/html.