# .html extension on last part of url in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to keep .html extension on last part of URL in wordpress, like http://teachingvolunteer.com/volunteer-programs/private-school.html . This site http://teachingvolunteer.com  was developed in  joomla framework and I want to save all URL for SEO purpose. Because If I developed site without .html extension then all indexed URL on search engine will be shown in not found page. That's why I want to preserve all URL in this site. Can anyone help me in this issue ?

Comment: This post may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13990456/3834042.

Comment: It is not working for me.My old site is developed in joomla framework now I want to use wordpress. I think you are aware of wordpress permalink structure while selecting post type. What I want to do is I want to keep .html extention in last part of URL of wordpress. for eg this is wordpress one of the url structure http://www.volunteeringnepal.com/volunteer-impact/women-empowerment-2013/, now I want same URL but .html extention on last like http://www.volunteeringnepal.com/volunteer-impact/women-empowerment-2013.html . Can I do this with wordpress ?